# Google Maps Geocoding API key usage count

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm developing an Android app requiring to show current position on a satellite styled google map. No routing, no address resolution and so on.

I wasn't able to understand if, for this purpose, my API key usage is unlimited or not.

According to the pricing plans [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#sup_1)

> Google Maps Android API: Unlimited free usage.
>
> Google Places API for Android: Default 1,000 free requests per day, increased to 150,000 free requests per day after credit card validation.

But checking [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) is stated that

> The Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect.

And they have 2500 daily usage limit per key.

I'm a bit confused, and in case my usage is limited, how the API usage is counted? Everytime i open the map and on overy update of the position?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They count everytime you call their API. They've different API and each API has its own counter and limit. You could call 500 times to Geolocation API and only call 100 times to Places API.

Comment: Ok, but in my particular case if i just display current location in Google Maps, do I fall under the case of limited number of API calls? Thanks

Comment: If you don't call neither of their API, you don't have to worry about anything. Displaying your location in Maps doesn't make any webservice call.

Comment: @oskarko do you know how frequent Google Directions API, send the new location to our web server? I know that on our webserver we have to attach a listener and Google Directions API will call our service, but how frequently? I would like to enable the users in my mobile app to see a polyline being filled in while they are driving. Please advise if I am on the right path here.